# Execute XQuery with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xquery

I'd like to know how to execute XQuery script using a JavaScript script. 
For instance a user fills a field, clicks on the submit button, a JS function is called and calls a XQuery script which is going to search informations in a XML database according to the parameter.
I'd like to call this XQuery script using a webpage : for example by calling http://localhost.com/myXQueryScript.xq?p=myparameter.

Thanks in advance! ;)

Comment: For now I have my XQuery script, my JS script but I don't know how to link both. I think I have to use XQuery server to execute my XQuery script but I don't know how to do. So if you can tell me how to do that... ;)

Comment: What XQuery engine and server are you using? This is not related to XQuery itself but to the processor you are using. For example BaseX comes with a REST interface so you could do something like `http://localhost/rest?run=XQueryScript.xq`

Comment: I work with BaseX. I didn't know about REST interface, I'm going to read the doc about that. Thanks!

Comment: @Hejk If you do, make sure also to read about RestXQ (http://docs.basex.org/wiki/RESTXQ) as it directly supports URL mapping and so you could put your script into such a function or call it from there. Imho RestXQ has many benefits over REST

Comment: For now I just need REST. So I tried to start the server (Databases-> Server Administration -> Start) and I tried to access http://localhost:8984/rest/. But the page is still loading even if I try something like that : http://localhost:8984/rest?run=test_server.xq. :/

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your description, your task has nothing XQuery-specific about it:  you want the user to fill out a form and your browser to retrieve information from a given resource.  The fact that the server will execute an XQuery as part of serving the resource in an implementation detail that does not need any particular attention in the client.

It would be difficult to find an XQuery engine that cannot be used in this scenario; many XQuery engines are able to listen on specified ports and accept HTTP requests from them.  The details of that interface are not standardized, so you will need to consult the documentation for the XQuery engine you're using.

On the client side, you will find many examples on the Web of using XmlHttpRequest(); that will enable you to do what you need.  Some users (me included) prefer XForms as providing a nicer way to implement the kind of thing you describe.

If I've misunderstood and you really want the XQuery to be evaluated in the client, you may want to look at [XQuery in the browser (XQiB)](http://www.xqib.org/).

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear enough, sorry.

I wanted my XQuery be executed by my BaseX server and I have succeeded. I started my server with the GUI interface but the server has to be started by using a terminal and start basexhttp server. So now I can execute a XQuery script by using, for example, http://localhost.com:8984/rest/myDatabase/?run=myscript.xq&$var="test".

Thank you anyway. ;-)